# Are Rust string literal values stored on the Heap?

Tags: rust, stack, heap-memory

Consider this simple code

```
fn main () {
    let mut s: &str = "hello";
    s = "hey";
    println! ("{}", s);
}
```

I have learnt that the string literals are immutable in nature. I agree with this because the variable 's' here refers to the address of the first character of the value "hello". So basically it's a pointer. Now, if I change the value of s to "hey", that is not replacing the value "hello" 'in-place' somewhere in the memory, but it's is essentially creating a new address location, storing the value "hey" in it and takes that address and point binds it to s. This is well understood.

But what I am confused is, since the size of the variables is a must to be known at compile time for them to be placed on the stack, then are string literals stored on stack too or is it the heap? May be they are stored on the stack for hardcoded values. But what if it is something like this which can be only determined at runtime?

```
fn main () {
 
    let mut user_input = String::new();
    let stdin = io::stdin(); // We get user input whose size we can't predict 
    stdin.read_line(&mut user_input);
    
    let ab = user_input.as_str(); // taking the value on heap and turning it to string literal and creating a new reference pointer 'ab' on the stack 

    println!("input {}, {} ", user_input, ab);

}
```

In the above where is the string literal value 'ab' stored? Stack or the Heap?

Comment: Note that `ab` is _not_ a string literal. A string _literal_ is a string that is _literally_ written in the code (as `"foo"`). `ab` is a string _slice_, and it is stored wherever the original string was stored: `user_input.as_str()` doesn't move the data, but simply creates a reference to it wherever it is (in this case, on the heap since that's where `user_input` is).

Comment: @Jmb Yeah, sorry. I was wrongly using them interchangeably. But that "wherever" must be on heap right? Or can such variable values be stored on the stack too?

Comment: @Thinker-101 that totally depends on what you derive your `&str` from, if from a `String` then it's pointing to the heap, for other sources it depends on that source, but usually it will be the heap. But there's nothing preventing you (or anybody else) from storing a byte array on the stack and create a `&str` to it.

Comment: If you write a string literal in the program, you will get a `&str` that lives in the executable `rodata` segment. If you get it from an array of `u8`, it will live on the stack (`let a: [u8; 4] = *b"abcd"; let s: &str = std::str::from_utf8 (&a[..]).unwrap();`). If you get it from a `String`, it will live on the heap. If you get it from a `static` variable, it will live in the data segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then are string literals stored on stack too or is it the heap?

Neither. string literals are generally stored in the "rodata" (read-only data) segment of the generated executable.

> But what if it is something like this which can be only determined at runtime?

By definition a string literal is not determined at runtime.

> In the above where is the string literal value 'ab' stored? Stack or the Heap?

A string *slice* (`&str`) is not a string literal, it's a pointer to a *non-owned string*. When you write `user_input.as_str()`, you just get a second pointer to the string stored in `user_input`.

See https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html

Comment: If the string slice is pointing to a hard-coded values then it understandable to have them in rodata. But what if the slice is not having a value initialised at compile time, like in the above example the variable "ab" must be pointing to a value on heap right?

Comment: No it doesn't *have to be* on the heap, see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

String literals have type `&'static str`. Note the `'static` part. They are placed in the read-only memory of the binary. It's not stack nor heap. Your OS allocates this memory when it starts process. This is the same as if you would write:

```rust
static FOO: usize = 42;
```

Rust will place this in a read only part of your binary. And you can obtain a `'static` reference to it, because this memory will be always valid, as long as your process lives.

As to the size of string literals, the compiler obviously knows its size, so it knows how much memory reserve for them. `&str` is actually called a wide, or fat pointer, because it has the size of two words (pointers). It holds a pointer to the memory, where the string literal (or any other string slice) starts and its length. You could think of it as `(*const u8, usize)`. So string slice can point at *any* memory containing a string. It doesn't matter if it is a stack, heap, or some other data segment in the binary.

You can read [a chapter on slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-03-slices.html) from The Rust Book, to better understand this concepts.

Comment: Even `'static` doesn't mean it's a string literal though, it just means the reference is valid for the lifetime of the program. *Usually* that's literals because they're stored as part of the program itself, but [`String::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.leak) can return a `'static` slice from a dynamic allocation.